# Nested enumeration numbering

Tags: lists, numbering, enumerate, nesting

I write homework assignments in LaTex and the assignments are always divided into subparts (i.e. Problem 1 is divided into 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ...). Currently what I do is I have nested enumerations, but the numbering isn't exactly what I'd like. To number the subparts, I am currently using:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}.}
```

However, this produces

```
1.
2.
...
```

and what I'd like it to be is

```
1.1
1.2
...
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
```

to change the way nested enumerations are set (without brackets `()`) and in a sub-enumeration form that is `\arabic`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Second
    \item Third
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Fourth
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​
```

The [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) is actually the de-facto list processing/setting package. Here's such a take on your enumeration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
    \item Second
    \item Third
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Fourth
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​
```

`label*` appends the suggested key-value to the parent `label`. Of course, global setting is also possible.

Comment: If you need to `\label{}` and `\ref{}` items in your list, the first option gives a bad `\ref` (the \enumi part appears twice). The enumitem method avoids this.
Also, FYI: the global options look like: `\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*.} 
    \setlist[enumerate,2]{label*=\arabic*.}`