# Nested enumerate labels with parent label appended plus a single set of enclosing parentheses

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, nesting

I want to have a list like

```
(1) foo
   (1.1) foo
   (1.2) foo
(2) foo
```

I am using the package `enumitem` and

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
   \item foo
\end{enumerate}
```

I know that i can append the parent label with `label*=`, but that leads to (1).1.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: duplicate: [nested-enumeration-numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78842/nested-enumeration-numbering)

Comment: @cmhughes I don't think so -- the parenthesis problem is special.

Comment: @lockstep though making the parenthesis the only difference............hmmmm so

Comment: @azetina Check the answers of the supposed "original" -- for the present question, you can use neither `\theenumi` nor `\label*`.

Comment: @lockstep You are right....i take it back

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is how it can be done using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
  \item foo
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*)]
    \item foo
    \item foo
  \end{enumerate}
  \item foo
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​
```

You need to define the nested labels *without* the labelling format of the parent. The counters for the levels of `enumerate` are `enumi`, `enumii`, `enumiii`, while `\arabic*` refers to the current level counter.

Answer (score 15):

You can get this automatically, that is, forgetting to add `[...]` to each environment, with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{jana}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[jana,1]{label=(\arabic*)}
\setlist[jana,2]{label=(\arabic{janai}.\arabic*)}
\setlist[jana,3]{label=(\arabic{janai}.\arabic{janaii}.\arabic*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{jana}
\item A
\item A
  \begin{jana}
  \item B
  \item B
    \begin{jana}
    \item C
    \item C
    \end{jana}
  \end{jana}
\end{jana}
\end{document}
```

Choose a more sensible environment name, of course, changing also the occurrence of the string; for instance, if you choose `myenum`, you will say `\arabic{myenumi}`, `\arabic{myenumii}` and so on.

This provides up to three levels, add more levels with the same pattern if needed.

[image]

One can also change the format of the labels: for instance

```
\newlist{labelist}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[labelist,1]{label=(\Alph*)}
\setlist[labelist,2]{label=(\Alph{labelisti}.\arabic*)}
\setlist[labelist,3]{label=(\Alph{labelisti}.\arabic{labelistii}.\arabic*)}
\setlist[labelist,4]{label=(\Alph{labelisti}.\arabic{labelistii}.\arabic{labelistiii}.\arabic*)}
\setlist[labelist,5]{label=(\Alph{labelisti}.\arabic{labelistii}.\arabic{labelistiii}.\arabic{labelistiv}.\arabic*)}
```

will define formats

```
(A)
  (A.1)
    (A.1.1)
      (A.1.1.1)
        (A.1.1.1.1)
```