# Related enumeration inside another enumerate environment

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate, nesting

How may I have a enumeration using the enumerate environment from which the inner environment counter relates to the item number which is already there for a previous environment?
Using an [already answered post]([Nested enumeration numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78842/nested-enumeration-numbering)), when I enter the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[1),‎label*=\arabic*‎‏), noitemsep]
\item % item number is 1)
Hello
\item % item number is 2)
How are you?
\begin{enumerate}[1), ‎label*=\arabic*‎‏), noitemsep]
\item % item number is 2.1)
I'm fine, thank you!
\item % item number is 2.2)
What about you?
\end{enumerate}
\item % item number is 3)
Good!
\item % item number is 4)
Do you know where is he?
\begin{enumerate}[1., ‎label*=\arabic*‎‏. noitemsep]
\item % item number is 4.1.
No!
\item % item number is 4.2.
Sorry
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

But I don't get the desired output. What I want is to get something like the figure below, if I enter something like the following:

[image]

Comment: Do you want `4.1.`  or `4.1)`?

Comment: I want something changeable, indeed when I type something like `‎label*=\arabic*‎‏.` changes the sub-enumerate environment to ‍‍‍‍‍‍`4.i.` form.
But at first, I need to know how I can make something like `2.i)` numbering format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `enumeration` is strange here, therefore I use a new list named `strangenumerate`

Since `label*=` cannot be applied here for the deeper nested levels (it prints a `)`, there are some other strategies:

- Make a conditional on the level of nesting and change the `label` according to this
- Refer directly to the counter of the current level, i.e. `strangenumeratei` here.

---

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{strangenumerate}{enumerate}{2}

\setlist[strangenumerate]{noitemsep}
\setlist[strangenumerate,1]{label={\arabic*)}}
\setlist[strangenumerate,2]{label={\arabic{strangenumeratei}.\arabic*)}}
\begin{document}

\begin{strangenumerate}
\item % item number is 1)
Hello
\item % item number is 2)
How are you?
\begin{strangenumerate}
\item % item number is 2.1)
I'm fine, thank you!
\item % item number is 2.2)
What about you?
\end{strangenumerate}
\item % item number is 3)
Good!
\item % item number is 4)
Do you know where is he?
\begin{strangenumerate}[label={\arabic{strangenumeratei}.\arabic*.}]
\item % item number is 4.1.
No!
\item % item number is 4.2.
Sorry
\end{strangenumerate}
\end{strangenumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gahir: You're welcome. Happy TeXing

Answer (score 3):

Without using any extra packages, just redefine `\theenumii`, `\labelenumi` and `\labelenumii`:

```
 \documentclass{article}

  \renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
  \renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi)}
  \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii)}
  \begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Firat item
    \item Second item
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item First subitem of second item
        \item Second subitem of second item
      \end{enumerate}
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item First subitem of fourth item
        \item Second subitem of fourth item
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```