# Multiple nested numerating with arabic numbers

Tags: numbering, enumerate, arabic

I need to numerate my document like:

> ```
> 1. Something
>   1.1. Something2
>     1.1.1. Something3
> ```

With the nested code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Something
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Something2
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Something3
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I achieve:

> ```
> 1. Something
>   1.1. Something2
>        i. Something3
> ```

Is there any way to do it the way I want it, the way above? How many times can I nest arabic numbers in that sense?

Thanks to all!

Some small edit: I managed to do it like this:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Something
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Something2
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item[1.1.1] Something3
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But I consider it as a quite lame way.

Comment: You can customize these and other properties of lists with the `enumitem` package.

Comment: Are these really enumerations or simply sections of the document?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, @AlanMunn, all given in my question is just example, my code looks differently.

Comment: What I'm asking is whether this is how the sections of your document are supposed to look like, or whether these nested enumerations would themselves be embedded within sections or subsections of a document differently numbered.  If the latter, then use `enumitem` (I can add an answer). If the former, then using `titlesec` would probably be more appropriate solution.

Comment: Yes, this is exact hierarchy, I don't nest this anywhere. I tried with "enumitem", but it didn't really happen. Here is the code, but it didn't manage to compile: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78842/nested-enumeration-numbering The error is this:"! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}"

Comment: by default latex allows 5 levels of nesting and can easily be set to use `\arabic` at all levels, you could use enumitem package but no package is really needed.

Comment: if you get `undefined` error on `\documentclass` then you did not use latex so you would get that error on every latex document. you need to use pdflatex not pdftex to process the document

Comment: @AlanMunn yes and no: if you want to indent the subsection body and not just the titles, using a list is easier than using the section hierarchy.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes that's true. I've deleted my comment. But then the linked question in the comment: [Nested enumeration numbering](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/78842) is a duplicate.

Comment: @AlanMunn agreed.

Comment: @AlanMunn If I run
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First
      \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
        \item Second
        \item Third
      \end{enumerate}
      \item Fourth
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
Error:
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300)
    entering extended mode
    ("bla_bla_directory"
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    l.1 \documentclass
                      {article}
    ?

Comment: @David Carlisle, please have a look at my reply to AlanMunn above. :)