# Nested arabic enumeration without last dot

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate, labels, enumitem

I like to change the labeling of an enumeration to the following structure:

```
1 First Item 
  1.1 First Sub-Item 
    1.1.1 First Subsub-Item  
    1.1.2 Second Subsub-Item  
  1.2 Second Sub-Item   
2 Second Item   
3 Third Item
```

[Similiar questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78842/nested-enumeration-numbering) have already been asked and the following code using `label*=\arabic*.` (and which is also part of the official [enumitem documenation](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=de)) is always the accepted answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}
\begin{legal}
  \item First Item 
  \begin{legal}
    \item First Sub-Item 
      \begin{legal}
        \item First Subsub-Item 
        \item Second Subsub-Item 
      \end{legal}
    \item Second Sub-Item 
  \end{legal}
  \item Second Item 
  \item Third Item 
\end{legal}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this solution puts an dot `.` after the last level of enumeration and therefore gives the following result:

```
1. First Item   
  1.1. First Sub-Item  
    1.1.1. First Subsub-Item  
    1.1.2. Second Subsub-Item   
  1.2. Second Sub-Item   
2. Second Item   
3. Third Item
```

Is it possible to define the label in such a way that it is not [1.1., 1.1.1., etc.] but instead [1.1, 1.1.1, etc.]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing @moewe's comments, here's a solution that requires only two separate `\setlist` instructions. The first `\setlist` instructions pertains to all list levels; the second affects just the numeric labels of level-1 items.

[image]

In addition, if you would rather not have any extra vertical whitespace between any of the items, simply provide the instruction `\setlist[legal]{nosep}` after the `\newlist` directive.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=.\arabic*}
\setlist[legal,1]{label=\arabic*}

\begin{document}
\begin{legal}
  \item First Item 
  \begin{legal}
    \item First Sub-Item 
      \begin{legal}
        \item First Subsub-Item 
        \item Second Subsub-Item 
          \begin{legal}
            \item First Subsubsub-Item
            \item Second Subsubsub-Item
          \end{legal}
        \item Third Subsub-Item
      \end{legal}
    \item Second Sub-Item 
  \end{legal}
  \item Second Item 
\end{legal}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd suggest the starred `label*` for items further down than first level: `\setlist[legal,2]{label*=.\arabic*}
\setlist[legal,3]{label*=.\arabic*}
\setlist[legal,4]{label*=.\arabic*}` Or is there an advantage to hard-coding the counters using `label`?

Comment: Even better. Make only the first one special: `\setlist[legal]{label*=.\arabic*}
\setlist[legal,1]{label=\arabic*}`

Comment: @moewe - Many thanks for these suggestions! I've edited my answer to implement the second suggestion.

Comment: Looks perfect! Thank you both for the quick answers!