# How to put a repeated word "Step" before this enumerate?

Tags: lists, enumerate

How to put a repeated word "Step" before this enumerate [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78842/nested-enumeration-numbering)?

Step 1. text
Step 1.1 text
Step 1.2 text
Step 2 text

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
    \item Second
    \item Third
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Fourth
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use `[label*=Step \arabic]`, or define a new enumerate-like list, say `enumsteps`and define its layout in the preamble, to avoid repeating the optional arguments in the document body each time you want to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Bernard . Can you help me to add a new define  for enumerate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a code defining a new list type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newlist{enumsteps}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[enumsteps,1]{label=Step \arabic*. }
\setlist[enumsteps,2]{label=Step \arabic{enumstepsi}.\arabic* }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumsteps}
  \item First
  \begin{enumsteps}
    \item Second
    \item Third
  \end{enumsteps}
  \item Fourth
\end{enumsteps}

\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working, you saved me.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!